# adding behavior without schema file

Tags: php, propel, symfony-2.5

Currently I am dealing with `'glorpen bundle'` and stuck in implementing Behavior to user class without adding it to user schema.
Can anybody help me to figure this out? Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do U mean with adding it to the schema?

Comment: im using FOSUserBundle for user. I need to add some behavior to user class for that i have to override FOSUserBundle's schema file. And i need to define FOSUserBundle as my app's parent. Which i think is not good. So, i need another way and i saw that Glorpen bundle has two behaviors (entend and event), which adds these behaviors to user class without overriding FOSUserBUndle's schema. so i need to know how it implements these behavior to our user class?

Comment: The only way the propel model creator task will add a behavior to a class is by adding it into the schema afaik

Comment: Is it possible to add a behavior in our userclass without overriding schema file like in glorpen bundle??

Comment: Some options.. Modify the propel generator class or modify one of the current applied added behaviors

Comment: i cant modify the user class(FOSUserBundle) since its a third party app. and also i get behavior from another bundle. How to do that?

Comment: U'll have to alter something right? :)